# How to run same cronjob in multiple Environment in same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, whenever

I have used Rails 5,Capistrano Gem and Whenever Gem. I have a server which have multiple environments.

When i update cronjob on server by capistrano, it override it inplace of running cronjob in multiple environment.

Example:
When I checked by **crontab -l** command on server

I see either

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/bhargav/sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112937/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-27 20:30:24 +0900
0 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/bhargav/sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112937 && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e production '\''TDayTenAsnSiireJissekiHeader.asn_siire_jidou_chakka'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/bhargav/sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112937/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-27 20:30:24 +0900

OR

# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/bhargav/staging-sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112656/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-27 20:27:33 +0900
0 16 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/bhargav/staging-sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112656 && bundle exec bin/rails runner -e development '\''TDayTenAsnSiireJissekiHeader.asn_siire_jidou_chakka'\'' >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/bhargav/staging-sites/tenpo_api_mdsql/releases/20180227112656/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-02-27 20:27:33 +0900
```

Answer (score 0):

In your schedule.rb file,
Add below line to use it only in production,

```
set :environment, :production
```

Or you can specify different environment to run different crons like below,

```
if Rails.env.production?
  every 1.day, :at => '12.00 am' do
    runner 'Name.update'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by the following code.

**This issue will occur when both your environments are on the same server you'll want to namespace them, or they'll overwrite each other when you deploy:**

> if Capistrano V2
>
> set :whenever_identifier, defer { "#{application}_#{stage}" }
>
> if Capistrano V3
>
> set :whenever_environment, ->{ "#{fetch(:stage)}" }